# How to take a screenshot of a loading spinner in playwright(ts / js)?

Tags: playwright, playwright-test, gui-testing

I have a button that after clicked will show the spinner with a 750ms delay, I want to capture the loading spinner to test the UI, I try bunch of methods but didn't work at all, the issues is after clicked it will loading and go the next page, the screenshot take the screenshot of next page, which is not my expected, here is my test code:

```js
    test.only('should show loading spinner for continue button', async ({ page }, testInfo) => {
      await page.route('**/*', async (route) => {
        await new Promise((f) => setTimeout(f, 1000));
        await route.continue();
      });
      const inputs = page.locator('#username');
      const continueButton = page.locator('form[data-form-primary] button[type=submit]');
      await continueButton.click();
      await expect(continueButton).toHaveScreenshot(testName('invalid', testInfo));
      await inputs.focus();
      await inputs.type('fake@email.com');
      await expect(inputs).toHaveScreenshot(testName('typing', testInfo));
      await continueButton.click();
      // always finish loading before capture the spinner screenshot.  how can take the screenshot when the spinner is spinning? 
      // await page.pause();
      await page.waitForTimeout(750);
      await expect(page).toHaveScreenshot(testName('spinner', testInfo), {
        fullPage: false,
        animations: 'allow',
      });
    });
```

Is there any methods that can take the screenshot when click the button at the same time ? Because after the second click for `await continueButton.click();`,  it already finished loading and jump to the next page

Comment: Do you need to use `waitForScreenshot`? I'd think asserting the existence/visibility of the spinner element is the easiest way to ensure a transitive element appeared. If you do need to check the spinner with a screenshot, I'd still use `locator().waitFor()` or `waitForSelector()`, then screenshot immediately after. If the spinner is still too short or racy, pause the page after the selector/visibility appears. A [mcve] would be useful--spinners can have arbitrary behavior and it's sort of hard to provide working code without running it.

Comment: Don't forget to [disable animations](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/pull/11870) on the spinner when screenshotting it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've tried `waitForScreenshot` and `locator.waitFor` and it will failed because hit the 30000ms times out in playwright config,  actually the spinner is a css pseudo-elements, I have tried `const spinner = page.locator('form[data-form-primary] button[type=submit]::before');` to see the spinner existence, but just wait until timeouts.

Comment: BTW, Do `animations` config have any specific effect on snapshots? I actually tried `disabled` and `allowed` refer from the [doc](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-screenshot), but it doesn't feel like it makes any difference!

Comment: I'm not sure offhand, on either count. I'd have to play with some code that reproduces these problems to make progress. The test code is only half the puzzle--the website under test (or a minimal reproduction of the relevant behavior) is equally important to see.